# find all element positions within a list of lists

Tags: python

Given that l = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5],[5,6]], is there a method to return a list that consists of all positions of 3 within l; i.e. return [2,3]. A sample code I wrote is:

```
def pos_in_lists(seq, elem):
    while i < len(seq):
        elem_pos = seq[i].index(elem)
        return [elem_pos]
```

When I run this, it only returns 2, which is not the result I want. What is my mistake? Also, is there a more simple way to solve my problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `[2, 0]` instead since 3 in `[3,4,5]` is at index 0?

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only returns a list with one element (`return [elem_pos]`). You need to have a list variable (`result`) outside the loop to keep track of the result of previous lists by appending to that list.

```
def pos_in_lists(seq, elem):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(seq):
        if elem in seq[i]:
            elem_pos = seq[i].index(elem)
            result.append(elem_pos)
        i += 1
    return result
```

Another simpler alternative is to use list comprehension

```
def pos_in_lists(seq, elem):
    return [l.index(elem) for l in seq if elem in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to increment "i" each loop
2. "return" forces the loop to exit.  That should be outside the loop at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the problem, Given list l = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5],[5,6]] and if we have to find 3, the output list should be [2,0].

Following mistakes are there in the code provided:

- The code is not working as i is not defined in your method before using it.
- We need to store positions of all 3 value present in the list, thus we need to have a list in which we store all the positions of 3 that we can find in the list. You have returned the result as soon as you have found one value. Thus, you are getting only 2.
- seq[i].index(elem) will throw value error if 3 is not in the list.

  **Solution**

  def pos_in_lists(seq, elem):

  ```
  res = []
  for innerList in seq:
      if elem in innerList:
          res.append(innerList.index(elem))
  return res
  ```

  pos_in_lists(l,3)

Result would be [2,0]

we can use list comprehension as well:

```
def pos_in_lists(seq, elem):
    return [innerList.index(elem) for innerList in seq if elem in innerList]
```